# Should I use spray or akka-camel to develop a new REST API?

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka, spray

I have to develop a new REST API using Akka, but I can't determine if Spray based akka-io is a better option compared to akka-camel extension. Seems that both APIs have non-blocking IO support. akka-camel looks easier but i don't know how it compares to Spray in terms of performance.

The scenario is simple: I have to receive a message via http REST endpoint, then I process the message and dispatch it to one of many external services via HTTP POST.

akka-camel is perfect for this, but I have to process millions of messages per day, so I wonder if the performance of akka-camel and Spray are comparable. Both are suitable for REST integrations, akka-camel is maybe more mature but Spray is maybe more modern.

The Akka Team is embracing Spray, so I wonder if they recommend Spray over akka-camel for REST based integrations.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your use case? I have a feeling that [Play](http://www.playframework.com) is good enough to fit your need.

Comment: Hi Max, I have to connect to many external services via HTTP. My project is a pure server-side app, it collects, transform and post data between many nodes and also provide some HTTP endpoints to external clients.

Comment: Why not constructive??? akka-io (spray based) and akka-camel are both maintained by the same akka team. But its functionality is overlapped. So I am asking what is the suggested api for new developments involving HTTP/REST.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate a bit of your findings/thoughs and what aspects you have questions regarding. It's easier to answer such a question then

Comment: Viktor Klang suggested me to use Spray. I will go that way.

Comment: Spray's routing DSL for declaratively defining a RESTful API is a thing of beauty; unless your API is trivial, I think you will appreciate it once you get to know it.  And Spray's async nature is a great match for the actor model.  Also note that the Typesafe team recently acquired Spray, and the Spray HTTP server (which is quite fast) will replace the HTTP server in Play.  I don't know whether the routing DSL will be incorporated into Play, but I certainly hope so.